# Calculate $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\arctan (\log (1+\sqrt x)) \sin^3(x^{3/4})}{(e^{\tan(x)}-1)(1-\sin^2(x))}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\displaystyle\arctan (\log (1+\sqrt x)) \sin^3(x^\frac34)}{\displaystyle (e^{\tan(x)}-1)(1-\sin^2(x))}$$

For WolframAlpha the result is: $0$.

I did those steps, using *Mac-Laurin*:

$$e^{\tan(x)}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+ o(x^2)$$
$$\sin^2(x)=x^2+ o(x^2)$$
Hence, the denominator became: $$x+ \frac{x^2}{2}+ o(x^2)$$
Then, I'm having issues with numerator:
$$\arctan (\log (1+\sqrt x)) = \sqrt x - \frac {x}{2} + o(x^2)$$
$$\sin^3(x^\frac34)=x^{\frac94}+ o(x^3)$$

Someone could say me how to deal with the Numerator, o give me a hint for solve it? Thank you.

Comment: What is your problem ? Can't you multiply and stop when the power exceeds $2$ ?

Comment: @Atmos $\sin^3(x^{\frac{3}{4}})$ exceeds 2, I should not consider it? I'm having issues on choosing the correct *Little-o*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that by standard limits

$$\frac{\arctan (\log (1+\sqrt x))\cdot  \sin^3(x^\frac34)}{(e^{\tan x}-1)\cdot (1-\sin^2 x)}=\frac{\arctan ( \log (1+\sqrt x) )}{ \log (1+\sqrt x)  }\cdot\frac{ \log (1+\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}\cdot \frac{\sin^3(x^\frac34)}{x^\frac94}\cdot \frac{\tan x}{e^{\tan x}-1}\cdot\frac{x}{\tan x}\cdot \frac{\sqrt x\cdot x^\frac94 }{x(1-\sin^2 x) }\to1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot0=0$$

indeed

$$\frac{\sqrt x\cdot x^\frac94 }{x(1-\sin^2 x) }=\frac{x^\frac74 }{(1-\sin^2 x) }\to \frac01=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Near 0,

$$\ln (1+X)\sim X $$

$$\arctan (Y)\sim Y $$

$$e^Z-1\sim Z \sim \tan (Z)$$

Comment: So the numerator should be: $\sqrt x x^{\frac94}$ and so $x^{\frac{11}{4}}$ ? But in this way I do not respect 2 order?

Comment: @NapMaster Yes. the denominator is equivalent to $x^\frac 12$. the function is equivalent to $x^{\frac {11}{4}-1} =x^\frac 74$$. it goes to zero.

Comment: @Salahmam_ Fatima, I find that the denominator should be $ x (1-x^2)$, for the rest I'm ok with you.

Comment: @NapMaster 1-x^2 goes to 1

Answer (score 0):

The term $1-\sin^2x$ in the denominator can be disregarded because its limit is $1$.

Thus the denominator is
$$
e^{\tan x}-1=1+\tan x+o(\tan x)-1=\tan x+o(\tan x)=x+o(x)
$$

For the numerator, you can set $t=\sqrt[4]{x}$, so you have
$$
\arctan(\log(1+t^2))=\arctan(t^2+o(t^2))=t^2+o(t^2)
$$
and
$$
\sin^3(t^3)=(t^3+o(t^3))^3=t^9+o(t^9)
$$
Thus your final expansion is
$$
(t^2+o(t^2))(t^9+o(t^9))=t^{11}+o(t^{11})=x^{11/4}+o(x^{11/4})
$$
Therefore your limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^{11/4}+o(x^{11/4})}{x+o(x)}=0
$$